# Babel with multiple paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, configuration, babeljs

I want to run babel-cli with multiple paths going to multiple destination folders. Here's my source structure:

```
/src
  /lib
  /server
  /something-irrelevant
  /more-such-things
```

I want to transpile only certain of those, e.g. lib and server. Can't seem to (easily) achieve this.

If I run:

```
babel src/server src/lib -d dist
```

My output is putting all *subdirectories* of `server` and `lib` and putting them directly into dist, not `server` and `lib` directories themselves.

Running multiple babel instances is suboptimal for my development flow. I could move `lib` under `server`, also not great as I'd like to keep the current structure.

Is there a config or option or a way I am missing to achieve this? So far I've mostly used babel with `gulp`, `babel-cli` is new to me.